# Xamarin.UWP local notification not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have implemented a code to send Local Notifications for a particular date and time on Android and iOS platform.And, My code is working for Android and iOS platform.In Android,I am using AlarmManager.
and in iOS, UILocationNotification for sending notifications. But , I didn't find any solution for the UWP platform to implement the Local Notification feature 
using Dependency Service as i got for Android and iOS platform. Is there any solution for sending local notifications for particular
 date and time for all the platforms including "UWP"(mandatory) in Xamarin.forms????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Xamarin.UWP local notification not working

If you want to make Local notification fore Xamarin.Forms, please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications). But it has not implement UWP platform. So we need implement [schedule notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.scheduledtoastnotification) within uwp and use dependency service to call it. And I have implement a simple you could refer.

**interface**

```
public interface INotificationManager
{ 
    int ScheduleNotification(string title, string message,DateTime scheduledTime);   
}
```

**Implement**

```
public class UWPNotificationManager : INotificationManager
{

    int messageId = -1;

    public int ScheduleNotification(string title, string message,DateTime scheduledTime)
    {

        messageId++;
        string TOAST = $@"<toast>
                  <visual>
                    <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
                      <text>{title}</text>
                      <text>{message}</text>
                    </binding>
                  </visual>
                  <audio src =""ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Mail"" loop=""true""/>
                </toast>";

        Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument xml = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(TOAST);

        ScheduledToastNotification toast = new ScheduledToastNotification(xml, scheduledTime);
        toast.Id = "IdTostone" + messageId.ToString();
        toast.Tag = "NotificationOne";
        toast.Group = nameof(UWPNotificationManager);
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(toast);

        return messageId;
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
private void OnScheduleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notificationNumber++;
    string title = $"Local Notification #{notificationNumber}";
    string message = $"You have now received {notificationNumber} notifications!";
    notificationManager.ScheduleNotification(title, message,DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
}
```

Comment: Hi , I followed your code and implemented the same. But I am facing an error related to initialize method . Have you implemented some interface for INotificationManager ??  Please help me out with this.

Comment: I just simplify interface, you could use code above directly.

Comment: Hi , I did tried to do so. But , it is throwing an exception "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' " in Main.xaml.cs file for NotificationReceived().  Can you provide me this same code in GitHub repo so that I can test it better ????

Comment: Sure, Please check this [link](https://github.com/msdnwptest/UWP-Support-Samples/tree/6b100f46608c3565de14492981e8c765f58048c5/LocalNotificationTest).

Comment: Okay I will try it once again and reach out to you , if I get stuck.

Comment: Hi , the app is running now. But , after clicking on the notification it is throwing tis exception : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index'
Have you got any idea related to it ????

Comment: Please remove Line 124 where in the UWP client project MainPage.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```